# Add a footer to a ListView in code

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing an app with a ListActivity with a footer whose contents are pretty dynamic based on certain situations. I wanted to use setFooterView like this:

```
Button addButton = new Button(this);
addButton.setText("Add");
addButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 35));
lv.addFooterView(addButton, null, true);
```

But it causes a Runtime exception. While using a layoutInflater may work with an XML layout (I use that for the header), how do I add a footer with programmatically constructed views?

Comment: please add your logcat..

Answer (score 2):

```
View            footerview;

footerview  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null);

Listview    = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
Listview.setAdapter(adp);

......

....


Listview.addFooterView(footerview);
```

I think this might be useful .

Comment: Yes, I know the XML way of doing it. Am looking for the result in pure code.